# Small Bug When When Appending Text To Multiline Text Box (C#)

Tags: c#, textbox

i have multiline text box in my form with existing text and I am trying to append text lines on new line and everything works fine but the first line always get added with the existing last line.

Example

text box holds this value

test1

and I am using below code to enter new line

```
txtMasterResults.AppendText(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, "line 2"));

txtMasterResults.AppendText(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, "line 3"));
```

and results looks like this

test1line2

line3

how can I fix the first line of textbox so I get the new text from secondline ?

Comment: Why are you using `String.Join` to prepend a single "\n" to a single string?

Comment: What is the problem with \n and simple +

Comment: @GSerg  when I use like this "txtMasterResults.AppendText(String.Concat("\n", autoSuggest));" also I getting the same result

Comment: @M.kazem Akhgary please check above reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would retrieve the old string, remove any newlines at the end, and then append the new content. So like this:

```
txtMasterResults.Text = txtMasterResults.Text.Trim() + "\n" + newText
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but the Environment.Newlines seems better for me

Comment: You can use that in place of the "\n", yes

Answer (score 1):

`String.Join` joins strings from an array using a delimiter. This is not what you want here.

Use:

```
txtMasterResults.Text += Environment.NewLine + "line 2" + Environment.NewLine + "line 3";
```

Note that
`txtMasterResults.Text += "something";` is the same as
`txtMasterResults.Text = txtMasterResults.Text + "something";`

Comment: this using an Environment.New Line before adding and removing any empty lines works fine now :)